# When schema_version & data version will be different?

Tags: magento2, setup, install-script, data-script

For example i don't have setup scripts in My module,can i ignore `setup_version` tag in `module.xml` file.

In m1 automatically modules installed,now it's first throwing an error(if we don't run setup upgrade command).
Why I need to manually run setup upgrade?

**What is the scenario `schema_version` and `data_version` will be different?**
I observed almost records in setup_module table contain same values.

Comment: automated upgrade was removed in favor of performance and  stability. Checking and comparing all modules version on each and every request is useless overhead in production. Upgrading database is the kind of action that should be under full control of developer, but not application itself.

Comment: In M2 there are two kind of database modifications you may have, by implementing two corresponding interfaces: "\Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface" and "\Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface". So, you can make upgrades to the database data without changing database schema. That's why versions of those live their own lives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`data_version` is the version of data added via the data scripts.

Those scripts are developed under the module folder under the `Setup/InstallData.php` and `Setup/UpgradeData.php`.

`schema_version` is the version of the database schema added via the setup scripts.

Those scripts are developed under the module folder under the `Setup/InstallSchema.php` and `Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

So the scenario when `data_version` and `schema_version` are different is the following:

- You have a module that have both setup and data scripts
- Normally you should run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` so both schema and data scripts will run
- Instead of doing this you first run `php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade` . **At this point the `schema_version` will be different to the `data_version`**
- Running `php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` will upgrade the data and make both versions the same

Comment: But why will anyone run those commands individually instead of `setup:upgrade`

Comment: @MagePsycho well yeah that's not a normal behavior. But as both commands are available it can happen right.

Comment: @MagePsycho There is no reason, I think it is completely redundant.